# Default sorting column in xe:Listview

Tags: xpages

I'm using the xe:Listview component from the Extension Library. The columns are added to the control by using xe:ListviewColumn components. The data source is the xe:viewJsonService. Currently I have a total of five columns with three sortable columns (sort = true in the xe:ListViewColumns). But I would like to set the default sorting to one of the xe:ListViewColumns. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the default sorting from the **REST service** itself. 
So on the xe:viewJsonService, add the programmatic name of the desired view column you wish to  sort by default to the sortColumn property, e.g. sortColumn="LastName". Then set the sortOrder to ascending or descending, e.g. sortOrder="ascending". 
But this scenario only works if the Notes view you are using for the REST service has sorting set on the column you want to sort, i.e. the LastName column though this column doesn't have to be the default sorting column from that view. 
Hope this helps.